# OutOfMemory exception is ASP.Net website after adding new package with large dll

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory, dll, out-of-memory

I have a Sitecore 8.2 website running in IIS on Windows 10. I recently tried to upgrade a nugest package to the latest version, but doing so caused my entire site to break with `System.OutOfMemoryException`. When I reverted to upgrade and restored the old dlls, the error was resolved. Is there something that can be changed either in IIS or in my website properties to allow to it to use the new dll without throwing a memory exception?

Comment: Which nuget package ?

Comment: Why cannot it be a bug of that NuGet package? Do some initial troubleshooting please.

Comment: If we would like to fix this issue by changing IIS property, we must make sure the crash is caused by an IIS configuration limit/isolation. So you may need to analyze the dump file to figure out where is the exception thrown. It will tell us whether this issue can be fixed by change IIS property.  But I think this exception probably have nothing to do with IIS itself so you might need to roll back the dll. Anyway, you could try to find the root cause first.

Comment: The package is IronPdf. I am trying to do troubleshooting with them but there really isn't anything I can do with the dll itself other than just roll it back, which means I can't use the updated dll which is necessary to resolve a bug in the version we're using.

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert I think you'd better review dump file. We need to figure out where and how is it come if the package is necessary for you.  The full call stack would help us in this case.

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert - I have the exact same issue adding IronPdf 2020.3.1.1 to my existing asp.net webforms project.  Have you had any success identifying the issue?

Comment: @FrancisSpor not yet, working with IronPDF support. I'd suggest contacting their support team